# failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms: play-services-games: 6.5+

Tags: android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

This project has been working for weeks. Yesterday, Android Studio pulled in some updates, and now gradle cannot find my play-services files. It has literally stopped building with no changes to the project - I didn't think this would happen with a gradle-based project.

[gradle sync error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfd7N.jpg)

When I click on "Install Repository and sync project", another window opens with the message:

Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-google-m2repository'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:6.5+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:6.5+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:6.5+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20'
}
```

Looking in my SDK manager, both "Google Repository" and "Android Support Repository" are installed. 
[SDK manager screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bSdp.png)

It is possible that I have two different SDK's, but not sure how to tell if I do, and not sure how to remove the extra one if this is the issue.

Comment: Try by removing "+" and add the latest version. For example                         compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4.89 '

Answer (score 0):

Removing the "+" and specifying the specific version allows me to build again. I'm actually using 6.5.87, as 8.4.0 caused some other issue.

Comment: i think the problem is not with the version of play services and it might be caused by something else..